# Creating a desktop GIS with arcpy analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

What is the problem with this code? I want to make a desktop GIS with this code in ArcPy. Can anyone help me?

[image: /]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include not just the code snippet that you ran but also the result i.e. was there an error message?

Comment: please take a look at my editted question,result doesnt have error, Is my code right? is it a way to automation vector to raster analysis with arcpy?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to have your code as text (like you did originally) rather than as a picture, please? The former is much easier to search and create tests from.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing several parameters in your code.  **[Polygon to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000030000000)** requires at least three parameters:

- in_features
- value_field
- out_rasterdataset

Secondly, there is no need to set it equal to "final_result".  Your result is set by  the "out_rasterdataset" parameter.

Comment: my project is finding a way to automation vector to raster analysis with arcpy library.i wonder the best analysis is feature to raster analysis for reaching to they want.am I right? please I am going to edit my question, i will be thankful if you take a look.